# Writing to a reference table in single-statement transaction don't work

Tags: singlestore

I have error

> WARN com.singlestore.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket - Error:
> 2549-HY000: Writing to a reference table in multi-statement
> transaction is not permitted on child aggregators. Try the command
> again on the master aggregator.

When I execute from DB client (Tx manual)

```sql
begin work;
insert into test_table (test_column)
values ('data');
commit;
```

Table was created with

```sql
create rowstore reference table test_table
(
    test_column  varchar(100),
    primary key (test_column) using btree
);
```

Reference table does not work from the child node for a single transaction also?